# Adding CSS tags to @extend classes

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am trying to extend an HTML class, and add specific CSS to that extension. Is there a way to do this? For example, something like this:

```
.countdown-close-button:before
{
   @extend .fa;
   @extend .fa-angle-double-right {
       position: relative;
       right: 100px;
   }
   @extend .fa-lg;
}
```

However this does not work.

Comment: Where the `@extend` comes from? Sass?

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned that - I just didn't know that was where it came from. I've heard about Sass but don't know what it is :/

Comment: so. you didn't write that code ?

Comment: It's code from my work, so no, however the stuff that doesn't work, I tried to add

Comment: If you don't know sass just add your css into the sass how you normally would, not amongst the other code but create a new page, name it _somethingappropriate.scss find the base style.scss (don't know what it's name will be), duplicate an @include line, change the name between the quotes to 'somethingappropriate'